# how to connect R to Anaconda3?

Tags: r, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 in my office PC.
I want to use R by Anaconda, but I cannot use the Internet in my office.
This means that, I cannot use

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

argument.
Is there ant good way connecting R to Anaconda?

Comment: @Hack. I installed Anaconda using USB  beacause I cannot use the Internet in my office. Since it is a rule of my company, I will not be able to use the Internet.

Comment: Your company has very strange rules. Anyway, I suggest that you follow my other suggestion then and get it working on your home computer (if you have the same operating system) then try to copy the working installation to your work laptop using the flash drive (USB).